# then is not a valid attribute name in Angular4

Tags: angular

In angular 4 i am using below html code

```
<div *ngIf="s.flow";then Avail else NotAvail></div>
<ng-template #Avail><td>{{s.flow.oo_status.status_info}}</td></ng-template>
<ng-template #NotAvail><td>Will Update</td></ng-template>
```

and i am getting below error

```
DOMException {message: "Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': ';then' is not a valid attribute name.", name: "InvalidCharacterError", code: 5, stack: "Error: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Elemen…10.144.100.162:3000/polyfills.bundle.js:16036:38)", ngDebugContext: DebugContext_…}
```

Comment: Don't you misplaced your quote ? I mean, the then should be in the *ngIf right ?

Comment: Got the issue i was using wrong syntax   this is the correct one ```<div *ngIf="s.flow; then Avail else NotAvail"></div>```

Comment: You are right @trichetriche

Comment: Well, you can mark it as resolved, @RahulSingh answered the same as me, just mark his answer as validated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div *ngIf="s.flow;then Avail else NotAvail"></div>
<ng-template #Avail><td>{{s.flow.oo_status.status_info}}</td></ng-template>
<ng-template #NotAvail><td>Will Update</td></ng-template>
```

It should be `*ngIf="s.flow;then Avail else NotAvail"` instead of `*ngIf="s.flow;"then Avail else NotAvail`

Answer (score 0):

ngIf syntax should be within double quotes. You have close it before the completion of condition.

Answer

```
*ngIf="s.flow;then Avail else NotAvail"
```

Not like this

```
*ngIf="s.flow;"then Avail else NotAvail
```